# Continue to other generators once a generator has been exhausted in a list of generators?

Tags: python, generator

I have a list of generators in a function `alternate_all(*args)` that alternates between each generator in the list to print their first item, second item, ..., etc. until all generators are exhausted.

My code works until a generator is exhausted and once the StopIteration occurs, it stops printing, when I want it to continue with the rest of the generators and ignore the exhausted one:

```
def alternate_all(*args):
    iter_list = []
    for iterable in args:
        iter_list.append(iter(iterable))
    try:
        while True:
            for iterable in iter_list:
                val = next(iter_list[0])
                iter_list.append(iter_list.pop(0))
                yield val
    except StopIteration:
        pass

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in alternate_all('abcde','fg','hijk'):
        print(i,end='')
```

My output is:

```
afhbgic
```

When it should be:

```
afhbgicjdke
```

How can I get this to ignore the exhausted generator? I would prefer not to use itertools and keep this same structure.

Comment: is there any reason you would prefer not to use `itertools.zip_longest`?

Comment: You are getting a `StopIteration` exception in `next(iter_list[0])` if the iterator has been exhausted. You should catch and handle it.

Comment: I'm learning generators and trying to understand them without simplifying the solution by just using itertools. This is an assignment requirement

Comment: I've tried to catch and handle the StopIteration exception, such as popping the generator out of the list, but it doesn't return to the code within the try block

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. You should handle it inside the `while` loop so that it keeps `yield`ing. You should then implement the logic to quit when all iterators are exhausted.

Comment: As an aside, you can create the iterator list with `iter_list = [iter(arg) for arg in args]`. And don't use `map` which is just an odd thing to have in a language that highlights list comprehensions like python does.

Comment: @tdelaney it's certainly more conventional to use a comprehension, although I personally prefer using `map` with named functions. I honestly don't understand Guido's hate for `map()`.

Comment: @newbiecoder11 thanks for the fun problem. I never saw anything anywhere near this level in school in lecture, let alone homework. Are you in an undergrad program? US? Abroad?

Comment: @ddejohn Haha, I am glad you enjoyed it. I am in an undergrad program in the US. Here, atleast in this program, the homework is usually the hardest part of the course.

Comment: What should the result be for `alternate_all("aaa", "bbbb", "cccc")`? `'abcabcabccb'` or `'abcabcabcbc'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. I tried to stay close to how your original code works (though I did replace your first loop with a list comprehension for simplicity).

```py
def alternate_all(*args):
    iter_list = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while iter_list:
        i = iter_list.pop(0)
        try:
            val = next(i)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        else:
            yield val
            iter_list.append(i)
```

The main problem with your code was that your `try`/`except` was outside of the loop, meaning the first exhausted iterator would exit from the loop. Instead, you want to catch `StopIteration` inside the loop so you can keep going, and the loop should keep going while `iter_list` still has any iterators in it.

Comment: @newbiecoder11 please accept this answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

How about the itertools-recipe `roundrobin`, straight from the `itertools` documentation? You'd still end up using `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`, though, not sure if that's a deal-breaker.

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Comment: OP explicitly states that they want to avoid `itertools`.